# xDebug not connecting with Netbeans

Tags: xdebug, netbeans-8

I have vm (centos 7, apache, php 5.4). Small test php script works with no problem. When i try to debug it Netbeans (8.0.2 on windows 8.1) shows 'waiting for connection' and nothing more happens. I am using ssh tunnel from vm port 9005 to host port 9005.

**xdebug log:**

```
Log opened at 2015-08-16 18:11:22
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9005.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/project/html/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="55867" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.3.2"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2015 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2015-08-16 18:11:24
```

**Result from php -i :**

```
xdebug support => enabled
IDE Key => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.auto_trace => Off 
xdebug.cli_color => 0 
xdebug.collect_assignments => Off 
xdebug.collect_includes => On
xdebug.collect_params => 0
xdebug.collect_return => Off 
xdebug.collect_vars => Off
xdebug.coverage_enable => On 
xdebug.default_enable => On 
xdebug.dump.COOKIE => no value 
xdebug.dump.ENV => no value 
xdebug.dump.FILES => no value
xdebug.dump.GET => no value 
xdebug.dump.POST => no value 
xdebug.dump.REQUEST => no value 
xdebug.dump.SERVER => no value 
xdebug.dump.SESSION => no value 
xdebug.dump_globals => On 
xdebug.dump_once => On 
xdebug.dump_undefined => Off
xdebug.extended_info => On
xdebug.file_link_format => no value
xdebug.force_display_errors => Off
xdebug.force_error_reporting => 0
xdebug.halt_level => 0
xdebug.idekey => netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.max_nesting_level => 256
xdebug.max_stack_frames => -1
xdebug.overload_var_dump => On
xdebug.profiler_aggregate => Off
xdebug.profiler_append => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger => Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value => no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir => /tmp
xdebug.profiler_output_name => cachegrind.out.%p
xdebug.remote_autostart => Off
xdebug.remote_connect_back => Off
xdebug.remote_cookie_expire_time => 3600
xdebug.remote_enable => On
xdebug.remote_handler => dbgp
xdebug.remote_host => localhost
xdebug.remote_log => /var/log/xdebug/debug.log
xdebug.remote_mode => req
xdebug.remote_port => 9005
xdebug.scream => Off
xdebug.show_exception_trace => Off
xdebug.show_local_vars => Off
xdebug.show_mem_delta => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger => Off
xdebug.trace_enable_trigger_value => no value 
xdebug.trace_format => 0 
xdebug.trace_options => 0 
xdebug.trace_output_dir => /tmp
xdebug.trace_output_name => trace.%c 
xdebug.var_display_max_children => 128
xdebug.var_display_max_data => 2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth => 3
```

I tried same config with XDebugClient and it worked -> so it is probably some issues with Netbeans.

**remote log with XDebugClient:**

```
Log opened at 2015-08-16 19:43:51
I: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9005.
I: Connected to client. :-)
-> <init xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" fileuri="file:///var/www/project/html/index.php" language="PHP" protocol_version="1.0" appid="58314" idekey="netbeans-xdebug"><engine version="2.3.3"><![CDATA[Xdebug]]></engine><author><![CDATA[Derick Rethans]]></author><url><![CDATA[http://xdebug.org]]></url><copyright><![CDATA[Copyright (c) 2002-2015 by Derick Rethans]]></copyright></init>

<- run -i xdc2
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="run" transaction_id="xdc2" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///var/www/project/html/index.php" lineno="13"></xdebug:message></response>

<- step_out -i xdc10
-> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="http://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_out" transaction_id="xdc10" status="stopping" reason="ok"></response>

Log closed at 2015-08-16 19:45:11
```

Comment: Problem has gone after restarting IDE

Answer (score 0):

in the settings you have

**xdebug.remote_host => localhost**

you should have the IP address of the remote machine (the one that runs netbeans), and i assume you should have the debuging port opened on windows firewall, so centos can connect back to that port in your netbeans. i haven't done remote debugging on other machines, always local, but this should work.

XDebug sample static ip/single developer:

- The IP of the server is 10.0.1.2 with HTTP on port 80
- The IDE is on IP 10.0.1.42, so xdebug.remote_host is set to 10.0.1.42
- The IDE listens on port 9000, so xdebug.remote_port is set to 9000
- The HTTP request is started on the machine running the IDE
- Xdebug connects to 10.0.1.42:9000
- Debugging runs, HTTP Response provided

Xdebug documentation: 
http://xdebug.org/docs/remote